# Trying to compute the error from comparing two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**Some context:** I have an explicit formula which is the exact solution to my problem. I have written code which implements a finite-difference scheme (explicit Forward-Euler, i.e: forward march-in-time iterative scheme) to approximate the solution to a partial differential equation (PDE). I have discretized the problem.

I want to compare these two and verify that the error between the exact solution and my approximation to the solution is indeed small. I have stored the values of the exact solution and the approximation in two `(NxM)` arrays, for each time-step and node in space.

Here is **the code I have written** to calculate the error:

```
# Compute the Error
E = np.zeros((N+1, M+1)) # so that E has NxM entries--one for each time-step and node in space
for m in range(1, M+1):
    for j in range(0, N+1):
        E_new = np.absolute(BS[j,m] - u[j,m])
        if (np.any(E_new >= E)): 
            E = E_new
        else:
            E = E

print 'Error = ', E
```

Here, I am taking `N = 100, M = 10,000`. If necessary, I can post the segments of my code where I calculate the arrays `BS` and `u`. Both are defined as arrays of the same size, and when I plot them, I am receiving an output which agrees with what the solution looks like. So I believe I am on the right track and that the rest of my code is working as it is supposed to.

However, when I run this particular segment in an attempt to calculate the error, I get that the error is roughly 29. I know this is wrong, the error should be small.

**My attempt to fix the problem:**

I think the problem possibly lies in the line containing `if (np.any(E_new >= E)):`. I want to check if any entry of the array `E_new` is greater than or equal to `E`. If I just run it with `if (E_new >= E):`, I get this ValueError: "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()."

I also tried running this: `if (np.any([E_new, E])):`, but again no luck. I received this error message, "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence". I have also tried using `np.all` in place of `np.any` in each of my attempts and this also does not seem to fix the issue.

Here is some **pseudocode** for what I wish to do:

```
E = 0
for i = 1,...,N:
    E_new = | BS(x_i) - u_i |
    if E_new >= E
        E = E_new
    else:
        E = E
    end
```

Any and all help is very greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance! I am really stuck here and I do not know how to move forward. I don't need a direct answer necessarily, but some insight as to what is causing the problem and a push in the right direction would be immensely helpful. Thanks again!!

Comment: Are the dimensions of E and E_new the same (in your original code)?

Comment: They should be. I have defined `E = np.zeros((N+1, M+1))`, and `BS, u = np.zeros((N+1, M+1))`. And since I have taken `E_new = np.absolute(BS[j,m] - u[j,m])`, I believe this means `E_new` is also `(N+1,M+1)`, since it is just the absolute value of the difference of the arrays `BS` and `u`.

Comment: Would it help to post my full code?

Comment: I think @Paul Panzer's answer does the trick here (assuming `BS` and `u` are the same shape because you can then perform mathematical operations on them just as if they were numbers).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would help to go through your program line-by-line:

```
# Compute the Error
E = np.zeros((N+1, M+1)) # so that E has NxM entries--one for each time-step and node in space
# to get NxM use np.zeros((N, M))

for m in range(1, M+1):
    for j in range(0, N+1):
    # any reason you start the outer loop at 1 and the inner loop at 0?

        E_new = np.absolute(BS[j,m] - u[j,m])
        # if BS is MxN (or (M+1)x(N+1)) BS[j, m] selects the entry at the
        # j-th row and m-th column which is a scalar. Similar for u, so in
        # the end E_new will contain a scalar

        if (np.any(E_new >= E)): 
        # at the first iteration this will compare the scalar E_new to the
        # array E resulting in an array of same shape of truth values
        # at all later iterations E will also be a scalar
        # the array allocated for E in the beginning will be garbage
        # collected

            E = E_new
        else:
            E = E

# why the error is so large in the end I can't tell you
print 'Error = ', E
```

And a suggestions, if I may:

If you want the maximum element-wise absolute difference as an error measure you can have that in one line which as a bonus executes much faster because it is vectorised. Assuming `BS` and `u` have the same shape:

```
E = np.abs(BS-u).max()
```